# wallet migration tool and password protected wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet.dat

Surely the Wallet migration tool by achow will port unencrypted legacy wallets to unencrypted descriptor wallets, but what will be the output for encrypted legacy wallets? unencrypted descriptor wallet (less-is-more), or encrypted descriptor wallet (funds-are-safu)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migrated wallet will be encrypted with the same passphrase.